# What causes table corruption error when reading hive bucket table in trino?

Tags: hive, trino

First of all, the format of the data cannot be disclosed, but the bucket table is created through the following table creation statements and options in hive.

**1. Create DDL**

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `schema1.ex1`(
`col1` string,
`col2` string,
`col3` string,
`col4` string
)
PARTITIONED BY(`date` string)
CLUSTERED BY (col1) SORTED BY(col2) INTO 32 BUCKETS
ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'...
```

**2. Set Property**

```
set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=1000;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=1000;
set hive.execution.engine=mr;
set hive.mapreduce.job.queuename=root.queue1;
```

**3. Insert Data (1 months)**

```
Insert into table `schema1.ex1` partition(date)
select col1, col2, col3, col4 from `schema1.existing_table` where date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-10-01'
```

**4. Read the data (in trino)**

Then, When I read the hive bucket table in trino, I got the following error

```
 'io.trino.spi.TrinoException: Hive table is corrupt. 
File 'hdfs://cluster1/hive/warehouse/schema1/ex1/date=2021-09-02/000026_0' is for bucket 26, but contains a row for bucket 9.
```

I don't know why the above error occurred. I would appreciate it if you could tell me the cause of the error and the solution.

I use hive 3.1.2 and trino-356.

Comment: What versions of Trino and Hive are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trino implements bucket validation. For this error to be thrown, the table is most likely truly corrupt.

Bucket validation verifies that data is in the correct bucket as it reads, and therefore attempts to prevent incorrect query results.

To test, the following [SET SESSION](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/set-session.html) clause can be added to your Trino query:

`SET SESSION hive.validate_bucketing=false`

The query will run, but it should be examined for incorrectly bucketed data.

Comment: Thank you. As you said, using the above options the query works. But how can I test if the table is not correct?

Comment: This is tricky to say. If you are able to reproduce with a small set of known/expected values, then the issue would be easy to discover by looking through the bucket. Otherwise a query could be run which utilizes the bucketing functions (typically something like a modulo) to try to discover which data is in the wrong place. Otherwise, if you are utilizing an older version of Hive, it would be advisable to upgrade in the hopes that the bucket writing issue has been fixed.  You can also create these bucketed tables with Trino (or Starburst) directly instead of Hive.

Comment: What version has the bucketing writing issue been fixed? I am currently using Hive 3.1.2.

Can you share the bucketing writing issue?

As a result of the current test, the hashing of the bucket created with mr was actually incorrect, and the bucket created with tez was created normally.

Comment: Apologies but I'm not quite sure of the details on the Hive side. I think it was introduced in 3, but not sure where it stands as far as resolution. I'm glad you were able to find the incorrect bucketing though.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know so far. Thanks to you, I have learned a lot. Have a nice day.